# Strange situation with @Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have strange situation with `@Autowired` 
App's main class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"khartn", "khartn.torrentsuploader.processor"})
public class NewMain implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(NewMain.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Component class:

```
@Component("MyDirectoryReader")
public class MyDirectoryReader {

    public  MyDirectoryReader ( ) {
        System.out.println("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
    }

    public void readDir() {
        try {
            String initialPathStr = NewJFrame.jTextField1.getText();
            System.out.println("initialPathStr " + initialPathStr);

            Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(initialPathStr);
            DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.{torrent}");
            for (Path path : stream) {
                System.out.println(path.getFileName());
            }
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When application starting, I see, what MyDirectoryReader class is initialized:

```
2015-04-11 21:42:29.405  INFO 9375 --- [.NewMain.main()] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@13d6044f: startup date [Sat Apr 11 21:42:29 SAMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"khartn", "khartn.torrentsuploader.processor"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(initMethod = "init")
    public NewJFrame mainForm() {
        System.out.println("init mainForm");
        return new NewJFrame();
    }

}
```

And in NewJFrame class have autowired field

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier(value = "MyDirectoryReader")
    MyDirectoryReader myDirectoryReader;
```

But when NewJFrame showed and button pressed,

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        if (myDirectoryReader == null) {
            System.out.println("myDirectoryReader is null");
        }
//        myDirectoryReader.readDir();
    }
```

then myDirectoryReader is null.

Why MyDirectoryReader is initialized as Component, but not autowired to the field?

Comment: Please show the code, where you use the NewJFrame.

Comment: `@Bean(initMethod = "init")
    public NewJFrame mainForm() {
        System.out.println("init mainForm");
        return new NewJFrame();
    }`

Comment: No, where do you use the bean mainForm?

Comment: Ahhh, you mean, what code of the init method?

Comment: Code of the init method http://pastebin.com/Uhqey2NQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code from the init method, you make the call `new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);`, however, when you create an object yourself, Spring doesn't know that and autowiring doesn't work. You have to use the Spring bean object itself. I think, if you change that line to `this.setVisible(true)`, it should work correctly (since the init method is executed when the bean is instantiated).